how can i generate 22 times randomly between 'A' and 'B' but 11 time maximum of each in python
i wana make a class that get a name and set it to random team between team A and team B and then sey it out but needs to be from 22 people and 11 in each team how can i make random not give me more than that amount that i want in python ?
i made this program but its not random on how many time maximum each of them have been chosen:
import random

class human:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name  

class fotbalist(human):
    def get_name(self):
        team = ['A','B']
        self.team = random.choice(team)
        print('%s is in %s team'%(self.name,self.team))


there was a mistake in my answer. deleted, edited and reposted. pl check

import random     

class fotbalist():

    # changed the variable name into names as the parameter is the list of all the names of players
    def __init__(self,names):
        self.names = names
        
    def get_name(self):
        i = 0 # to initiate iteration
        team_A, team_B = [], [] # 2 empty lists for each tean
        L = len(self.names)
        
        while i < L:
        
            team = [team_A,team_B] # to choose between random choice
            
            # if len(team_B) is not 11 the length of team_A is 11, , append players to team_B
            if len(team_B) != 11 and len(team_A) == 11:
                team_B.append(self.names[i])
                
            # if len(team_A) is not 11 the length of team_B is 11, append players to team_A
            elif len(team_A) != 11 and len(team_B) == 11:
                team_A.append(self.names[i])
                
            # if length of each team does not exceed 11                
            else:
                
                # select bet 2 teams and append the player
                self.selected = random.choice(team)
                self.selected.append(self.names[i])

            # Remove the selected name from the list of names
            self.names.remove(self.names[i])    
            
            L = L -1

        return [team_A, team_B]

# List of players' name. For convenience, I have given alphabet
# you can give a list of real names of the players
players = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V']

r = fotbalist(players).get_name()
print(f'Team A :{r[0]}') # index-0 of returned value
print(f'Team B :{r[1]}') # index-1 of returned value

Output:
Team A :['A', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'U', 'V']
Team B :['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S']


There was a mistake. So, deleted, edited and re-posted.
